# create a new file from a string of text

Tags: file, filenames, batch-processing

I need to create a series of files with the file name of a line of text in a text document. I am on a mac and don't know about scripting. Is there a simple utility or a Terminal command where I can drag and drop in the file with the text in it and it would make the new files in the same directory?
The text file would say:

```
Week    1   Session 1
Week    1   Session 2
Week    1   Session 3
Week    2   Session 1
Week    2   Session 2
Week    2   Session 3
Week    3   Session 1
Week    3   Session 2
Week    3   Session 3
Week    4   Session 1
Week    4   Session 2
Week    4   Session 3
```

And so on for 35 weeks, with 'Week' starting a new line. This is something I would have to make periodically.

Having searched for an answer, I can see plenty of file names to a text file but not much the other way.

I apologise if this appears too simplistic but I would appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Learn to code. Seriously. Find tutorial for a language like python and follow it, or go to one of many sites that offer free interactive courses. It is a very fun hobby and, even if such things don't interest you, it is still a very useful skill to have.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the advice but I did find out how to do it.

On the mac you open a Terminal window and write 'touch' then the file name(s). If there is a gap in the file name, you put it in double inverted commas like this: "file 1.txt" then a space and more inverted commas if you want a second file such as

"file 1.txt" "file 2.txt"

I used Numbers (like Excel) to make all the names and pasted it in.
And that way it all worked very quickly. Low tech I am sure, but quick and useful.

Hopefully that answer will be useful to someone like me in the future.

Comment: // , Would you please show us an example of the command? Also, where can we look up the docs for this?